# Most vs most of the

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, british-english, verb-agreement

> Most people are afraid of swine flu these days.

Is this correct or should we write "most of the people" in place of "most people"?

Answer (score 3):

'Most people are afraid of swine flu these days' is correct, especially if you are talking about *all* the people - the entire population of a country, for example.

'Most of the people' implies (to me, as a native BE speaker, at least) a smaller group which might be qualified, like 'Most of the people *we interviewed*', for example.

Comment: Right. Definite article use like _most of the people_ harks back to context and assumes that the addressee is already familiar with exactly who "the people" are. _Most people,_ on the other hand, refers to the entire population as a whole, unqualified.